# Why static_cast works but dynamic_cast fails?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

Suppose I have a base class and 2 classed derived from that. All the derived classes has its own logic that incompatible between them. The test application is as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
    
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int x) { m_x = x; }
    virtual int getResult() { return m_x; }
protected:
    int m_x;
};


class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedA(int x) : Base(x) {}
    int getResult() override { return m_x * 2; }
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedB(int x) : Base(x) {}
    int getResult() override { return m_x * m_x; }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Base *> objects;
    objects.push_back(new DerivedA(1));
    objects.push_back(new DerivedB(2));
    objects.push_back(new DerivedA(3));
    objects.push_back(new DerivedB(4));

    for(Base *object: objects)
    {
        DerivedA *obj = static_cast<DerivedA *>(object);
        if(obj != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << obj->getResult() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to get only 2 result i.e. that only instances of type `DerivedA` can be casted to `DerivedA` but not `DerivedB`. But to my surprise this is not the case. `static_cast` casts `DerivedB` to `DerivedA` without problem. Why is this happening? I can understand that if I would cast to `Base` but not that. At the same time `dynamic_cast` works as expected, i.e. casting `DerivedB` to `DerivedA` fails.

Comment: `static_cast` assumes that the programmer is doing the right thing. When you don't, dereferencing the resulting pointer has undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's precisely the difference between the two types of casts. `dynamic_cast` validates the conversion at runtime, and fails if the types don't match. `static_cast` checks the types at compile time and succeeds (i.e. compiles) if it can't determine that they cannot possibly match.

Comment: The joy of undefined behaviour is that things can mostly appear to work making the eventual crash difficult to find

Comment: I always assumed that `reinterpret_cast` relies on programmer but `static_cast` performs the validation at compile time.

Comment: @folibis: It does indeed perform the cast at compile time, but the behaviour is still undefined.

Comment: ok but so far what a difference between `reinterpret_cast` and `static_cast` in this case?

Comment: @folibis: Insofar that the behaviour on dereferencing a pointer set by either cast is undefined, there is no difference.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the trick now. Since the validation is performed at compile time, the compiler can't uniquely identify the real type of the class and assumes that pointer of type `Base` theoretically can be casted to `DerivedA`.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour on dereferencing a pointer that's the result of a `static_cast` of a `DerivedB*` to a `DerivedA*` is *undefined*. It's a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: Casting to an unrelated type is simply UB. Strict aliasing is of importance when the cast would have worked otherwise.